# Is m called the grading coefficient and equals to 1/2 or 1/3 in the following question?

Tags: diodes, body-diode

The following is an example from [Digital Integrated Circuit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130909963).

Consider the following silicon junction diode:

\$C_{j0}= 2 \times 10^{-3} F/m^2\$,
\$A_D = 0.5 {\mu m}^2\$, and \$ \phi_0 =0.64 V \$

A reverse bias of -2.5 V results in a junction capacitance of \$ 0.9 \times 10^{-3} F/m^2 \$.

$$C_j = 
\frac{C_{j0}}{(1 - V_D / \phi_0)^m} = \frac{2 \times 10^{-3} F/m^2} {(1 + 2.5 \hspace{1mm}V/0.64 \hspace{1mm}V)^{0.5}} 
\approx 
0.9 \times 10^{-3} F/m^2$$

The book seems to say m is 1/2, but m should be 1/3 according to this diagram:

[image]

Comment: @JRE Who do you think is correct?

Comment: Isn't that a purely empirical coefficient? Shouldn't it depend heavily on the diode?

Comment: @sx107 what value should be chosen for m in my case?